# Filter out multiple where not like

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I am trying to [RTM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses) but cannot see where the list of possible `where` operators are listed. I only see the basic examples of `>=`, `<>` and `like`. Anyways, I want to filter out any results that match multiple patterns.

If I use

```
->whereNotIn('fieldName', ['exactString1', 'exactString2'])
```

Then I filter these exact strings from my results. However I want to filter out multiple *patterns* (NOT LIKE) rather than multiple strings.

The patterns are generated **dynamically** so using an array would be preferable. So something like

```
->whereNotLike('fieldName', ['%string1%', '%string2%'])
```

I am using MySQL so I'm open to using a raw query is the query builder does not support this.

So if I have results of

```
string1_abc
string2_abc
string3_abc
```

then I would get

```
string3_abc
```

returned.

I cannot use a `whitelist` and the `blacklist` patterns are generated dynamically.

Comment: Could you please add a very brief example of what results you're looking for? Your question is good but it's a bit unclear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JoelHinz thanks for the feedback, updated

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. You'll need to go with multiple where clauses then. If the patterns are generated dynamically, that should at least be fairly easy.

Comment: @JoelHinz ...I actually can't think how to add multiple where clauses using the query builder using a loop. Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure, I'll get right on that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very basic example of how you can add multiple conditions on the fly to an existing query:

```
$patterns = [
    'field1' => ['pattern1', 'pattern2', 'pattern3'],
    'field2' => ['pattern4', 'pattern5'],
];

$query = MyModel::where('x', 'y'); // just an example of a query builder instance

foreach ($patterns as $field => $pattern) {
    $query->where($field, 'not like', '%'.$pattern.'%');
}

return $query->get();
```

It obviously won't look exactly like this in your application, but hopefully you get the idea. :)

Note that you don't have to do `$query = $query->where(...);` since you're transforming the existing query rather than creating a new one.

Comment: That's assuming `not like` is a functioning operator, I haven't seen that myself in Laravel...

Comment: Wow my brain is asleep haha and yes, not like does indeed work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'not like'`, like:

```
->where('fieldName', 'not like', '%string%')
```

Comment: So I have to use multiple where clauses then? There is no equivalent `whereNotLike('fieldName', ['%string1%', '%string2%'])`? I ask because the patterns are generated dyamically